# Is there a way to combine the LIKE and IN operators in a sequelize findall query?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a query that can take multiple words (partial or complete) from a search. The words are contained in an array of strings and then used to search multiple columns of a table.

I've tried combining the Op.like and Op.in operators a bunch of ways but can't seem to find a way to get them to work together.

```
const searchQuery = ['joh', 'do',]

const patients = await Patient.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { firstName: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchQuery + '%' }},
            { lastName: { [Op.like]: '%' + searchQuery + '%' }},
        ]
    }
});
```

The above code works fine on a single word but not multiple words like I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any such SQL function.  I suggest using js to dynamically build most of the WHERE clause, as shown below.

Hopefully the list of words is small - the resulting query could be huge...

```
const searchQuery = ['joh', 'do',]

let orArray = [];
searchQuery.forEach(word => {
   orArray.push(
      {
         [Op.or] : [
            {firstName: { [Op.like]: '%' + word + '%' }},
            {lastName:  { [Op.like]: '%' + word + '%' }},
         ] 
      }
    );
});

const patients = await Patient.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: orArray
    }
});
```